# Which 'sqlite' should be used to build an app on MacOs using Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, sqlite

I am porting app code that is running correctly on UWP, Android and iOS via Visual Studio and 'sqlite':

For UWP -> Visual Studio on Windows 10 and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite --- For Android -> Visual Studio on Windows 10 and Mono.Data.Sqlite --- For iOS -> Visual Studio For Mac and Mono.Data.Sqlite

Each of these builds and runs on actual devices, not just emulators.  All tools are up to date as of this writing.

I have tried to run very basic, startup database code from the app on MacOs and i get errors as shown below.

The code:

```
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;  // iOS version of code

public class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
    {
        SqlConnection ctx;
        string dbPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/Mydatabase.db";
        ctx.SqliteConnection("data source=" + dbPath);
        ctx.Open();
        ...
    }
```

`
Mono.Data.Sqlite blows up on ctx.Open - "The method or operation is not implemented" --- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite blows up on ctx.SqliteConnection("data...) - "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception"

I have also tried System.Data.SQLite, sqlite-net-pcl and sqlite-net.  These all blow up on the connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819083/running-sqlite-on-mono

Comment: @shadowraz  Thanks for the link.  It refers to exactly the same kind of issue I'm having.  I'll dig through all the stuff mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

With red face, I'm answering my own question.  Running sqlite on MacOs turned out to be as simple as adding *references* to Mono.Data.Sqlite, and System.Data to the project.  It also works fine with iOS projects.  Trying to take the NuGet *packages* route was getting me nowhere, as per my original question.

My delay in discovering this solution came from the fact that the reference to Mono.Data.Sqlite is not shown by Visual Studio on Windows.  But is clearly displayed as an option on Visual Studio for Mac.